# MySQL8 – 'caching_sha2_password requires SSL'

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I have changed to Mysql8 on my server.
I connect to the server through ssh.
With (e.g.) VScode Database explorer I can use the on the server, but from Python3 with MySQL connector, I don't.

On sever side, 'ssl_disabled=True,' solved the problem, but on my computer, I can not connect to the server's db.

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error

def create_connection():
    connection = None
    try:
        connection = mysql.connector.connect(
            host='host',
            port='port',
            user='user',
            passwd='passwd',
            database='db',
            ssl_disabled=True,
            )
        print("Connection to MySQL DB successful")
    except Error as e:
        print(f"Error in create_connection -->\n '{e}'")
    return connection

create_connection()
```

I try to run this and get:

```
 'caching_sha2_password requires SSL'
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!
If I use port 3307 instead of 3306, it works from the local machine, too!